# Uniform Convergence of $\sum f_n$ if $f(\sum f_n \to f)$ is uniformly continous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Consider a series of functions $\sum f_n$ on an interval $(a,b)$ ,
>   such that :
>
> 1.$\sum f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise
>
> 2.Both $\sum f_n$ and $f$ are continuous on $(a,b)$
>
> Then if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ then can we say that
>   $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $(a,b)$

This is not a question in any textbook , it is just a thought I got when reading about uniform convergence of series of functions.

Is this statement true , or are there any similar results regarding uniform convergence of series of functions ??

Answer (score 2):

No.

Take $f_n=x^n$ on $(0,1)$

Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise and not uniformly.

You can see this sequence as a series: $$f_n=f_1 +\sum_{k=1}(f_{n+1}-f_n)$$

Answer (score 2):

Take any sequence of continuous functions $(g_n)$ converging  point-wise to $0$ on $[a,b]$but not uniformly. Take $f_1=g_1$ and $f_n=g_n-g_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$. This gives a you  a counter-example.

Comment: Is there a theorem on similar lines that I can use for checking weather a given series is uniformly convergent or not